# Selenium Grid 2 - API version of /console page

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I am writing a status monitoring page for our test environment and would like a list of individual selenium/webdriver nodes which are registered with the Grid server.  I can do this by scraping the information on /console but I was wondering if there is an api-like way.

Basically I'm looking to do obtain output similar to that of TestSessionStatusServlet but for all registered nodes.

Mark

Comment: @see my answer [here][1] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9227160/selenium2-servlets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's currently anything shipping in Grid that provides that.  However, you can register your own servlet when you start the hub up.  If you subclass org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.RegistryBasedServlet you'll have full access to the Registry and can pull out any info that you need.  I've done something very similar so I could audit when a node  goes down.