# Selenium2 Servlets

Tags: selenium-grid

i'd like to add the own servlets  by starting of selenium-server-standalone-2.19.0.jar -servlets, but cannot figure out how to do it.

is it possible to find the developer's guide about selenium2 servlets?

one example would be also very nice.

tnx a lot!

a working solution of mine:

1) checkout of http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/tags/selenium-2.19.0

2) created HubServlet which extends from RegistryBasedServlet

package org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.alpha;
...
public class HubServlet extends RegistryBasedServlet {
   ...
}

3) building

./go clean release (only once)

./go //java/server/src/org/openqa/grid/selenium:selenium:uber (everytime i change something on org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.alpha.HubServlet)

Answer (score 4):

The solution which worked for me:

1. svn checkout of the selenium2 sources from googlecode

   ```
   $ svn co http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/tags/selenium-2.19.0 selenium
   ```
2. changed to the selenium dir

   ```
   $ cd selenium
   ```
3. adding servlets folder "alpha"

   ```
   $ mkdir -p java/server/src/org/openqa/grid/web/servlet/alpha
   ```
4. adding servlets classe(s)

   ```
   package org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.alpha;

   public class HubServlet extends RegistryBasedServlet {
      ...
   }
   ```
5. making HubServlet.jar

   ```
   $ ./go clean //java/server/src/org/openqa/grid/web/servlet/alpha:HubServlet
   ```
6. getting from googlecode selenium-server-standalone-2.19.0.jar

   ```
   $ wget http://selenium.googlecode.com/files/selenium-server-standalone-2.19.0.jar -O selenium-server-standalone-2.19.0.jar
   ```
7. merging jar(s)

   ```
   $ mkdir tmp
   $ (cd tmp; jar -xf "build/java/server/src/org/openqa/grid/web/servlet/alpha/HubServlet.jar")
   $ (cd tmp; jar -xf selenium-server-standalone-2.19.0.jar)
   $ jar -cfM selenium-server-standalone.jar -C $dir_sel_build/tmp .
   ```
8. starting selenium-server-standalone.jar with the "-servlets" parameter

   ```
   $ java -jar selenium-server-standalone.jar -role hub -servlets org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.alpha.HubServlet
   ```

you will see something like:

```
15.03.2012 16:25:07 org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncher main
INFO: Launching a selenium grid server
15.03.2012 16:25:08 org.openqa.grid.web.Hub <init>
INFO: binding org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.alpha.HubServlet to /grid/admin/HubServlet/*
361 [main] INFO org.seleniumhq.jetty7.server.Server - jetty-7.x.y-SNAPSHOT
392 [main] INFO org.seleniumhq.jetty7.server.handler.ContextHandler - started 
o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/,null}
400 [main] INFO org.seleniumhq.jetty7.server.AbstractConnector - Started 
SocketConnector@0.0.0.0:4444
```